# Rewrite URL to access files from directory off root, but not show in path

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to run a version of a Wordpress site on my localhost without going through too much hassle of changing url's, etc.

I have figured I will add a line in my hosts file to route `domain.com` to `localhost`. I just need a way to route `/` to look for files in `/directory/directory/`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not create a `/directory/directory/` on localhost also?

Comment: @anubhava Because of Wordpress' way of writing every URL as an absolute URL. I don't want to have too many hassles when I put the site back on the server.

Comment: I wasn't asking for any WP change. Whatever directory structure your WP install has just maintain it on localhost.

Comment: It doesn't, that the whole point of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this, didn't seem to do anything:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory/directory/$1 [L]
```

I used GasMask to route `domain.com` to my `localhost`.